# How to do grouping by based on date with adding additional properties

Tags: java

I have got Person DTO having 4 Properties

```
class Person {
            private String name;
            private String city;
            private int age;
            private String dateOfBirth;
            // Setters and getters 
}



// sample data      
personList.add(new Person("Mike", "London", 38, "01/01/1981"));
                personList.add(new Person("John", "London", 38, "01/02/1981"));
                personList.add(new Person("John", "Bristol",38, "01/06/1981"));
                personList.add(new Person("Steve", "Paris",06, "03/07/2013"));
```

I am trying to group data from the above List  based on  dateOfBirth Property .(only considering Month and Year, date is ignored)
If the User falls under same Month and Year , adding  the ages , sample output below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making this simple, first i would stream the `List<Person` and then collect them into `Map<String, List<Person>>` using groupingBy based on `Date` output pattern `outputPattern`, Since `SimpleDateFormat` is a legacy i would like to use `LocalDate`

```
 String outDate = LocalDate.parse(p1.getDateOfBirth(),
                                  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(patternInput))
                                 .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(outputPattern));
```

Now combining this with `groupingBy`

```
 Map<String, List<Person>> groupResult = personList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p->LocalDate.parse(p.getDateOfBirth(),
                           DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(patternInput))
                               .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(outputPattern))));
```

Now use the `forEach` and print the output in required format

```
  groupResult.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("Date : "+ k+
        ", Age : " + v.stream().mapToInt(Person::getAge).sum()+
        ", UniqueCityCount : "+v.stream().map(Person::getCity).distinct().count()));
```

**Finally Output**

```
Date : Mar-19, Age : 34, UniqueCityCount : 1
Date : Jan-81, Age : 97, UniqueCityCount : 2
```

You can also use `YearMonth`, but still it is same thing if you need your own formatting

```
  String ym = YearMonth.parse(p1.getDateOfBirth(), 
                  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(patternInput))
                  .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(outputPattern));
```

**Output**

```
Mar-19
```

By defauly [year-month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) returns this format **A year-month in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12.**

Answer (score 0):

## `Map< YearMonth , Set < Person > >`

For date-time work, you are using terrible old classes that were supplanted years ago with the adoption of JSR 310. You should be using *java.time* classes instead.

For the birth date member on your class, use the data type `LocalDate`. This represents a date without a time-of-day and without a time zone.

Tip: Use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) strings for serializing date-time values as text. For a date-only value, that would be YYYY-MM-DD.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" ) ;
```

For the aggregating by year-month, use the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( ld ) ;
```

Why are you passing the age to constructor? You pass the birthdate, so the age can be calculated. The age should be returned by getter method that dynamically calculates elapsed years, never stored.

Also, your example data is nonsensical, with the age not matching the birthdate.

```
Person p = new Person( "Alice" , "Johnson" , "1981-01-02" ) ;
int age = p.getAge() ;
```

Implement `Person::getAge( ZoneId )` method.

Determining today's date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Pass the zone to the `getAge` method.

```
public int getAge( ZoneId z ) {
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
    Period age = Period.between( p.getBirthDate() , today ) ;
    int years = age.getYears() ;
    return years ;
}
```

Alternatively, pass a `LocalDate` (today’ date) to `getAge` rather than a time zone.

Define your map as mapping year-month to a set of people.

```
Map< YearMonth , Set< Person > > = new TreeMap<>() ;
```

For each `Person` object, get the `YearMonth` for their date of birth. For each such year-month, make a set of `Person` objects if not already existing. And add the person to the set.

When done, loop the map to retrieve each set of people. Loop each `Person` object in that set. Calculate the age, and sum.

If you want to get fancy, that reporting age-sum code could be done with streams.

Comment: This is a sample data , so age is not correct , but the data must be grouped in that way only