# Can we group in Java 8 the Data based on Month and Year only

Tags: java

Here in this example , it is grouping the data based on the entire date .

Can we group the Data based on Month and Year only

```
package com;        
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

        public class GroupData {
            public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
                try {
                    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>(); // Date Format is MM/DD/YYYY
                    personList.add(new Person("Mike", "London", 35, "01/01/1981"));
                    personList.add(new Person("John", "London", 21, "01/02/1981"));
                    personList.add(new Person("John", "Bristol",41, "01/06/1981"));
                    personList.add(new Person("Steve", "Paris",34, "03/07/2019"));

                    Map<LocalDate, List<Person>> personByMap = new HashMap<>();
                    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    personByMap = personList.stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> LocalDate.parse(p.getDateOfBirth(), dtf)));



                    System.out.println(personByMap.size());




                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        }

        class Person {
            private String name;
            private String city;
            private int age;
            private String dateOfBirth;



            public String getDateOfBirth() {
                return dateOfBirth;
            }

            public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
                this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
            }

            public Person(String name, String city, int age, String dateOfBirth) {
                this.name = name;
                this.city = city;
                this.age = age;
                this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public String getCity() {
                return city;
            }

            public void setCity(String city) {
                this.city = city;
            }

            public int getAge() {
                return age;
            }

            public void setAge(int age) {
                this.age = age;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sure, but then don't use a LocalDate as the key, use a YearMonth: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display a Property in HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57229272/display-a-property-in-hashmap)

Comment: I that question i added my answer and showed you how to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a `LocalDate`, use [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html):

```
personByMap = personList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> YearMonth.parse(p.getDateOfBirth(), dtf)));
```

I also suggest you to directly store the date of birth as a `LocalDate`:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private int age;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    // ...
}
```

And then you can do:

```
personByMap = personList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> YearMonth.from(p.getDateOfBirth())));
```

Comment: How do i store data here                     personList.add(new Person("John", "London", 21, "01/02/1981"));

Comment: Replace the string literal with `LocalDate.parse("01/02/1981", dtf)`. @Lavanya